# MySQL connection error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to execute the following PHP script (called test1.php, say) on a web server running Apache. The script tries to connect to a MySQL server:

## ===============================================

```
$myHost = "localhost";

$myUser = "anyone";

$myPwd = "1234";

$link = mysql_connect($myHost,$myUser,$myPwd);

if (!$link) {

die(mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n");

}

echo "Connected successfully.\n";
```

## ================================================

I kept receiving errors like this:

2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

However, as root or normal user, I can execute the above script successfully from the shell:

shell>php /var/www/html/test1.php

Connected successfully.

I am confused and am grateful if anyone has any hints about this problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Execute `<?php phpinfo();` both under apache and CLI and compare `mysql.default_socket` value.

After you get valid socket path (from CLI phpinfo) - you can specify the same to the php.ini, or right in your code:

```
$link = mysql_connect($myHost . ':/tmp/mysql.sock', $myUser, $myPwd);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now after I changed SELinux option to Permissive; it was Enforce.